# how do I include the qcserial module in the kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration, embedded, cross-compilation

I need a kernel compiled, featuring the qcserial module to have support for the Huawei EM 680 model (Gobi 3000). I got kernel 3.11.6 and can find the appropriate source file in `./drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.c` but how can I make sure it gets compiled and loaded statically? I can't find it in the kernel config dialog... any ideas?

I'm cross compiling this kernel for an arm AT91 CPU and I need support for above cell modem...

"*As of linux-3.1.1-1 the device is detected by the qcserial module*" - is what I found on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gobi_Broadband_Modems

**edit modem-manager**

after installing modem-manager, i tried to launch it but I don't really get anything, see the 
screen output below:

```
# modem-manager  
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  ModemManager (version 0.5.2.0) starting...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Novatel
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin ZTE
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Option High-Speed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Longcheer
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Ericsson MBM
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Samsung
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Nokia
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin SimTech
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Huawei
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin MotoC
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin X22X
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Generic
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Sierra
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Option
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Wavecom
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Linktop
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin Gobi
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  Loaded plugin AnyData
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB1) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS1) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS2) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS3) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS4) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS0) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB1) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB1) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB1) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS1) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS1) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS1) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS2) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS2) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS2) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS3) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS3) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS3) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS4) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS4) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS4) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS0) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS0) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS0) opening serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB1) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB1) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS1) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS1) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS2) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS2) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS3) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS3) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS4) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS4) serial port closed
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS0) closing serial port...
modem-manager[2417]: <info>  (ttyS0) serial port closed
```

Which is kind of odd as when I plugin the modem, in dmesg I now get:

```
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14f1
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: Product: Huawei EM680 w/Gobi Technology
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Incorporated
qcserial 1-1:1.1: Qualcomm USB modem converter detected
usb 1-1: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
qcserial 1-1:1.2: Qualcomm USB modem converter detected
usb 1-1: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB1
qcserial 1-1:1.3: Qualcomm USB modem converter detected
usb 1-1: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

Comment: by the way have you looked at [ModemManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/)?

Comment: @yegorich I installed it (with apt-get) even tho my device doesn't show up in http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/SupportedDevices/ - and also, I can not find a modemmanager or ModemManager binary... how can I see where apt-get installed it? Thanks!

Comment: Strange. In Xubuntu 13.04 binary is called `modem-manager`, if I compile it from source it is called `ModemManager`. I have used it only with Buildroot so far.

Comment: @yegorich I could've figured this out myself, it is called `modem-manager` here. See edit above please!

Comment: See this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1079359) in Ubuntu. By the way this modem seems to support QMI (`CONFIG_USB_NET_QMI_WWAN` option in kernel). It also seems as if `mm` version Debian provides is rather old. Version 1.0.0 with `libqmi` support would be better. But as long as you can connect via `pppd`, you don't necessary need `mm`.

Comment: @yegorich I just realized a few min ago that my kernel is missing the ppp moule so i'll compile and load that and will go from there I guess... Thanks for your continued support! Much appreciated!

Comment: @yegorich hm, I now loaded the ppp module but things still don't seem to work as they should, seems like nothing's able to talk to my modem at all, I configured a ppp session and tried to talk to `/dev/tyyUSB0`,`/dev/tyyUSB1` & `/dev/tyyUSB2` at 38400 baud but don't get anything on any reply anywhere...

Comment: First of all try if modem reacts at AT commands on one of the `/dev/ttyUSB0 - /dev/ttyUSB2` ports. Stop all services, that could use these ports and then open one of these ports via `minicom` (baudrate doesn't matter IMHO) and type **AT**, you should get **OK**. I had one modem (Sierra Wireless), that was working under Windows, but under Linux none of the ports reacted to AT commands, till I made a firmware update.

Comment: @yegorich I did this but didn't get a response on any of the ports... and `minicom` shows `Offline` on the bottom, any other ideas by any chance?

Comment: That's not good. Do you have a PC, where you can insert your modem and see, if it works on a modern Linux distro? Is there newer firmware? Have you tried to activate QMI driver? otherwise - no idea. As I sad, I had such situation with Sierra and only firmware upgrade helped.

Comment: @yegorich yep, on my notebook which is running Kubuntu 13.10, I installed `wvdial`, ran `wvdialconf` and the modem got recognized immediately on `/dev/ttyUSB2` - connected with `screen` to `/dev/ttyUSVB2` @ 9600bps & sent `AT` - I succesfully got `OK` as answer so the modem should work...

Comment: @yegorich `BANG!1 I've figured it out! Power USB connector on notebook & data USB to my embedded board, `wvdialconf` now found it at `/dev/ttyUSB1` ! Great! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look into `drivers/usb/serial/Makefile`, you'll see that `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_QUALCOMM` is responsible for this driver.

Execute `make menuconfig` and goto "Device Drivers"->"USB support"->"USB Serial Converter support"->"USB Qualcomm Serial modem"